# Unable to change rect of UIView when call status ends in ios objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnotificationcenter

I need to adjust views when call status increases the status bar height to 40. I used `- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application willChangeStatusBarFrame:(CGRect)newStatusBarFrame` to post notification using `NSNotificationCenter`

It works when the status bar height increases from 20 to 40, but NSNotificationCenter doesn't seem to post notification when the status bar height reduces from 40 to 20 as the UIView frame is not assigned to the desired `CGRectMake`

I'm working on an old project so there is no storyboard.

Here's what I tried

In viewDidLoad -

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(statusBarChangedForBottmView:) name:@"STATUSBARCHANGED" object:self];
```

and the method

```
- (void) statusBarChangedForBottmView:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSDictionary *data = [notification userInfo];
    NSString *statusBar = [data valueForKey:@"frame"];
    NSLog(@"status bar in edit card = %@",statusBar);
    if ([statusBar isEqualToString:@"STATUS"])
    {
        if (STATUSBARINCREASED)
        {
            [self.bottomView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height-60, self.view.frame.size.width, 45)];
        }
        else
        {
            [self.bottomView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height-40, self.view.frame.size.width, 45)];
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Why aren't you simply using Apple's `UIApplicationWillChangeStatusBarFrameNotification`?

Comment: @GuillaumeAlgis I tried that, but didn't work. So I tried something different, still didn't work. Don't know why

Comment: I added break point in my selector but, that never gets invoked. Any ideas why?

Comment: See the edit in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**:

Make sure you that you subscribe to the notification from *any* object. ie:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(statusBarChangedForBottmView:) name:@"STATUSBARCHANGED" object:nil]; // <-- object:nil
```

This is not the current object (`self`) which is posting the notification, it's your AppDelegate.

From the doc:

> *notificationSender*
>
> The object whose notifications the observer wants to receive; that is, only notifications sent by this sender are delivered to the observer. If you pass nil, the notification center doesn’t use a notification’s sender to decide whether to deliver it to the observer.

If you get this working, I'd still recommend using `UIApplicationWillChangeStatusBarFrameNotification`, instead of posting your own notification from `- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application willChangeStatusBarFrame:(CGRect)newStatusBarFrame`.

---

I just tested on a fresh project, using `UIApplicationWillChangeStatusBarFrameNotification` works like a charm.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(statusBarChanged:) name:UIApplicationWillChangeStatusBarFrameNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)statusBarChanged:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSDictionary *userInfo = notification.userInfo;
    NSValue *statusBarRectValue = userInfo[UIApplicationStatusBarFrameUserInfoKey];
    CGRect statusBarRect = [statusBarRectValue CGRectValue];
    NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGRect(statusBarRect));
}
```

**Output:**

Receiving a call:

```
2014-10-09 17:53:31.407 test-so[14775:8742949] {
    UIApplicationStatusBarFrameUserInfoKey = "NSRect: {{0, 0}, {375, 40}}";
}
```

Call ended:

```
2014-10-09 17:53:35.881 test-so[14775:8742949] {
    UIApplicationStatusBarFrameUserInfoKey = "NSRect: {{0, 0}, {375, 20}}";
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks.. That worked. Will you please guide me to extract 40 and 20 from the above NSRect?

Comment: @Wadhiv Sure. I updated my answer to extract the `CGRect` from the notification `userInfo` dictionary.

Comment: NSValue *statusBarRectValue = userInfo[UIApplicationStatusBarFrameUserInfoKey]; ??

Comment: Please read [the doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplication_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/data/UIApplicationWillChangeStatusBarFrameNotification): "The userInfo dictionary contains an NSValue object that encapsulates a CGRect structure expressing the location and size of the new status bar frame. Use UIApplicationStatusBarFrameUserInfoKey to access this value." This is because NSDictionary cannot contain non-object types (like CGRect), so we wrap the CGRect in a NSValue.

Comment: Also, `userInfo[UIApplicationStatusBarFrameUserInfoKey]` is the same as `[userInfo objectForKey:UIApplicationStatusBarFrameUserInfoKey]`. It's a modern ObjC shorthand syntax.